# Why is this sequence of instructions faster?

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, x86, clang

I was comparing GCC and Clang output for the evaluation of a floating point expression and stumbled upon a performance difference I couldn't explain.

Source code

```
float evaluate(float a, float b) {
    return (a - b + 1.0f) * (a - b) * (a - b - 1.0f);
}
```

GCC 7.2 (-std=c++1y -O2) produced

```
evaluate(float, float):
  subss xmm0, xmm1
  movss xmm2, DWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
  movaps xmm1, xmm0
  addss xmm1, xmm2
  mulss xmm1, xmm0
  subss xmm0, xmm2
  mulss xmm0, xmm1
  ret
.LC0:
  .long 1065353216
```

While Clang 5.0.0 (-std=c++1y -O2) produced

```
.LCPI0_0:
  .long 1065353216 # float 1
.LCPI0_1:
  .long 3212836864 # float -1
evaluate(float, float): # @evaluate(float, float)
  subss xmm0, xmm1
  movss xmm1, dword ptr [rip + .LCPI0_0] # xmm1 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero
  addss xmm1, xmm0
  mulss xmm1, xmm0
  addss xmm0, dword ptr [rip + .LCPI0_1]
  mulss xmm0, xmm1
  ret
```

GCC seems to prefer `movaps` over `movss`, even though `movss` is sufficient in this case. As noted by [Peter Cordes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224132/peter-cordes), this is actually better as using `movaps` avoid stalls from partial updates to XMM registers.

GCC uses three instead of two XMM registers.

Clang uses two constants and only addss for them rather than only having one and using subss to subtract one from a register.

I graphed the instruction-level true dependencies for these sequences and Clang's is one level shorter.

Performance-wise, quite differently from what I expected, **GCC version is about 30% faster**.

I've tested this on Intel (Broadwell) and AMD (Bulldozer) CPUs and I don't see why the GCC code would be any faster here.

**The original benchmark used bad inline asm code. After creating two object files (one with GCC, one with Clang) for the C++ code of the function of interest and linking against them with GCC the performance difference disappeared.** Peter Cordes has hinted that this might be because of `-O1` leaving out the `.p2align` directives.

I looked at the compiler output of the new benchmarking method and asserted that both implementations of `evaluate()` have the exact same code as above and that the compiler is actually calling them.

Comment: what optimization flags did you use to produce the gcc/clang output?

Comment: @tobi303 I've updated the question with that information. However, more than knowing why GCC produced better code, I want to know why GCC's machine code is better in this case.

Comment: ah ok, then I really misunderstood the question. However, after reading it again, imho it is quite clear and it was just my stupidity ;)

Comment: gcc performs one load utilizing registers more thoroughly, while clang performs two loads.

Comment: You are measuring throughput here, so the depth of the dependency graph is less important than the plain count. Btw a mov between registers like that usually has no latency on modern CPUs.

Comment: @VTT given that these are constants and they are probably always in L1D, should it be noticeable?

Comment: `movss xmm1, xmm0` *merges* into `xmm0`.  Using `movaps` is the best choice for copying an xmm register holding any FP value, even when only the low element is useful.

Comment: @PeterCordes you are correct, the optimization manual even suggests using `movaps` if you can. But I am guessing this alone wouldn't explain the 30% throughput difference, right?

Comment: On what CPU?  Haswell?  Ryzen?  Bulldozer?  Silvermont?  A dorito?  Or is it 30% on both your Intel and AMD CPUs?  CPU microarchitecture can matter a *lot* for specific asm loops.  And what version of `gcc -O1` are you using?  Why do you want to include function call / ret in your measurement, anyway?  Obviously you can't let the functions inline with that clunky hack of using a basic ASM statement (no input/output operands), because they destroy xmm regs without telling the compiler.  But it just seems bad, and likely to lead to alignment-sensitive behaviour, or a fluke.

Comment: @PeterCordes roughly 31% on both Broadwell and Bulldozer. GCC 7.2.1.

Comment: Ok, those both have zero-latency `movaps` (handled with register-renaming).  So the extra instruction on Intel isn't costing a vector ALU port.  When you profile it, are you bottlenecking on ALU port pressure, or on something else?  How many instructions per clock with `perf stat ./a.out`?  And it's a consistent 31% even with a warm-up (of running this a few times back to back), not just a side effect of Turbo kicking in for the 2nd loop?

Comment: Even if I let both loops run for roughly 30 seconds I get from 28 to 33 percent. 1.68 IPC on Broadwell, 1.54 IPC on Bulldozer. I don't know on what I am bottlenecking. How can I find this out?

Comment: You need to run only one loop or the other to get the IPC for one loop.  You look for bottlenecks by considering various microarchitectural limits and seeing if you're close to any of them.  For example, you might be close to bottlenecked on load-uop throughput. BDW and BD can both run 2 loads per clock.  The caller does 2 loads of FP constants for args, one store to the stack (`call` pushes a return addr), and your function does 2 or 3 loads (1 or 2 FP constants + `ret`).  But you have room to spare.  With 12 insns in the loop, ~1.5 IPC means you're taking about 8 cycles per iteration

Comment: 8 cycles is long enough that probably front-end problems can't fully explain it.  But note that **`-O1` leaves out the `.p2align` directives** before the functions, so your nasty hack to emit the asm you want resulted in unaligned functions.  You should check whether one of them starts right before a 16-byte boundary, and if so try fixing it (by modifying the compiler's asm output, or using `-falign-functions=16`).  I don't expect that will fix the slowdown, especially if your gcc puts the clang function first.

Comment: BTW, there's a simple way to compile with `-O3`: put functions in separate files, and don't use link-time optimization so they're opaque to the optimizer.  That way you can actually use the object-file produced by `clang`, instead of putting its code into inline asm.

Comment: @PeterCordes that is a much better way of doing this. I will give it a try.

Comment: After removing all asm(), relying on GCC and Clang to generate their own code and using GCC with -O3 to link against those object files, they have essentially the same throughput. Will update the question with this.

Comment: Ah, so maybe it was a mostly a front-end / code-alignment issue.

Comment: If you can't put it into a separate file, it may be possible to put a `__attribute__((noipa))` on the function. Useful for godbolt's compiler explorer. Prevents inlining, but also interprocedural constant propagation+function cloning.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb That's good to know. But if I need two versions from different compilers this won't cut it, right?